# Constructing a Contour Plot with Three Different Arrays Corresponding to X, Y, and Z in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, grid, contour

If I have specific x and y values corresponding to a z value separated by array, how would I make a contour plot? For example:

```
Array 1 (X):
1
4
6
7
8
2
6

Array 2 (Y):
7
7
8
9
0
1
2

Array 3 (Z):
8
9 
7
1
2
2
3
```

Would I have to do X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(X, Y) and shape the Z array somehow? Is there another way to do this without using meshgrid? Also, if I add a fourth array and name it Z1 with the same x and y values corresponding to a particular Z1, can I plot this contour plot together with the first contour plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have a regular grid, using triangular surface interpolation may be a good choice.

In this example and the above one, if you have longer data, you only have to check the boundary of the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

sns.set(style="white")

x = np.array([1,4,6,7,8,2,6])
y = np.array([7,7,8,9,0,1,2])
z = np.array([8,9,7,1,2,2,3])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

nptsx, nptsy = 100, 100
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nptsx),
                     np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nptsy))

triangles = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
tri_interp = tri.CubicTriInterpolator(triangles, z)
zg = tri_interp(xg, yg)

# change levels here according to your data
levels = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
colormap = ax.contourf(xg, yg, zg, levels,
                       cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                       norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=z.max(), vmin=z.min()))

# plot data points
ax.plot(x, y, color="#444444", marker="o", linestyle="", markersize=10)

# add a colorbar
fig.colorbar(colormap,
             orientation='vertical',  # horizontal colour bar
             shrink=0.85)

# graph extras: look at xlim and ylim
ax.set_xlim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
ax.set_aspect("equal", "box")

plt.show()
```

This is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do an interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.array([1,4,6,7,8,2,6])
y = np.array([7,7,8,9,0,1,2])
z = np.array([8,9,7,1,2,2,3])
points = np.column_stack((x,y))
values = z.T

gridx, gridy = np.mgrid[0:8:100j, 0:8:100j]
gridz = interpolate.griddata(points, values, (gridx, gridy), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121,projection='3d')
ax1.plot3D(x,y,z, 'k.', ms=10)
ax1.contour(gridx,gridy,gridz)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,projection='3d')
ax2.plot3D(x,y,z, 'k.', ms=10)
ax2.plot_wireframe(gridx, gridy, gridz,rstride=5,cstride=5)
plt.savefig('contour_wire.png')
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, but say that I have a large data set of 411 points for each x, y, and z arrays. What would I need to change in this program?

Comment: No, I just have three arrays with (x(array 1),y(array 2)) corresponding to a particular z values( array 3).